# Eclipse plugin Based menu development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have enabled a new menu through `plugin.xml` using `menuContribution`, now I want to change the color and size of the text in this menu, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API to change color/font on `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem`